# Implement observer pattern in Java Servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, design-patterns

Is it possible to implement a observer pattern (i.e., get notification from server) using only Java Servlet?

Maybe a more generic question would be, is it possible to implement observer using HTTP protocol?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of [PUSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898066/java-push-from-server-to-clients)?

Comment: you have more options nowadays like web sockets...

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva While using Servlet how can use web sockets ?

Comment: @Wudong Have you got solution for this question? Please Tell...